# Fedora distribution update pop-up after fresh installation

Tags: fedora, kickstart

We are doing a kickstart installation of Fedora 10 at our place. I am quite intimidated by the distribution update pop up that comes up after the O/S installation. I want a keyword to put into the kickstart file that would stop Fedora from intimating with an update pop-up.

Is it possible to include such a switch in the kickstart OR a script that could be added to post.bash?

Comment: Also; please don't cross post to *both* StackoverFlow and ServerFault.

Comment: Sorry. Point taken.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude all the PackageKit packages; we use something like this:

```
%packages
-PackageKit*
-gnome-packagekit
-kpackagekit
```

Comment: But isn't packagekit responsible for the software updates? Actually we want the software updates to go as is, but not the distribution update. 
In System->Preferences->Software Update Preferences there is a "Check for major upgrades" settings, does that means that changing the setting here would affect the distribution updates? I have kept it to never, and haven't received a distribution update pop-up since my last install.

Comment: You can still manually update software by using yum/rpm. We totally remove PackageKit so we can control when package updates get applied via yum. I'm not aware of a kickstart option to control that update preference, but if you can find out which file it's modifying, you could put something in a %post script to do the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, I'll post once I find out which file it modifies. I guess other Linux distros have an option that one could turn on the Security updates only...I dunno if Fedora applies security updates as a part of distribution update or has any other mechanism. Ideally, it'll be nice if they are separate.

Comment: Oh my...upon doing Update System Fedora does charts out the kind of updates available.

Answer (score 0):

Your also have the option is to run an update in the %post section that would bring the installation up to date:

```
%post
/usr/bin/yum -y update >> /root/post_install.log 2>&1
```

This would still allow you to run updates later; however, a new fresh installation would no longer require it.

Comment: Actually we do not want a distribution update to happen. But thank you, I didn't know about this.

Comment: @Sayan - You'd prefer to be on an OS without patch support?